# How to just take the Parameters of Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have Arrays like this

```
array['Mountain' => 1, 'Forest' => 2, 'Space' => 1];
```

How can i just take the Mountain, Forest, and Space then insert them into new Arrays in Php?

i wanted output like this :

```
output['Mountain', 'Forest', 'Sky'];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `array_keys` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

```
$a = ['Mountain' => 1, 'Forest' => 2, 'Space' => 1];
print_r(array_keys($a));
```

Will output

```
Array ( [0] => Mountain [1] => Forest [2] => Space )
```

Comment: Please link to the English version of documentation, as the main site is English only. Also, questions about basics such as this one are almost always already covered, so please look for duplicates and flag instead of answering. The goal of the site is not to recreate the same content over and over again.